# How to prove that $U$ is one-one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $T: X\to Y$ and $U:Y\to X$ be function ,and suppose $T\circ U=I_Y$ where $I_Y$ denote the identity function on $Y$

Prove that $T$ is onto and  $U$ is one-one

**My attempt** : For $T$ is onto proof:

let $y$ be any element  of $Y$.If  we take $U(y)=x$ then $T(x)=T(U(y))=(T\circ U)(y)=I_Y(y)=y$

Thus for every $y \in Y $, there exist exist an $x \in X$ such that $T(x)=y $

this implies $T$ is onto

**My confusion** : How to prove that $U$ is one-one?

Comment: Just follow the definition: $\forall y,y' \in Y \ (U(y)=U(y') \implies y=y')$. By the way, this is not real analysis, this is more about elementary set theory.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of left inverse :

$T : X \to Y $ is a left inverse of $U : X \to Y$ if
$T ( U (y) )= I_y=y$ for all $y \in Y $

From  the definition  $U$ has left inverse

Let $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ such that
$U(y_1) = U(y_2) \in X$. By definition of left inverse we have then $$y_1 = (T \circ U)(y_1) =(T\circ U)(y_2) = y_2 \implies  y_1=y_2$$

Therefore  $U$ is one- one